# Run sequence of images / animation within a AsyncTask

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I created a custom ProgressDialog which has a lively ImageView. But this giving error for use within a AsyncTask execution.
AsyncTask out of work. I tried to use the animation with a runOnUiThread and not worked. How can I use this animation while running AsyncTask?

layout_progress.xml (only image)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLoading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@anim/loading"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
```

loading.xml (animation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list android:id="@+id/animation" android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_4" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_5" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_6" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_7" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_8" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_9" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load5_10" android:duration="150" />
</animation-list>
```

method show of the custom progress dialog

```
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        setContentView(layoutId);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLoading);

        final AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

        final Runnable run = new Runnable() {


@Override
        public void run() {
            anim.start();
        }
    };

    imageView.post(run);

    //test 2 - doesnt work
    /*
    final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            anim.start();

            imageView.post(this);
        }
    };

    activity.runOnUiThread(run);

    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in an AsyncTask. Manipulation of the UI should be done only in the UI thread.

There is a simple example of what you are trying to achieve here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Try and start the animation after you are sure that the ImageView has been attached to the view hierarchy. Quoting the link I posted:

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android brings your window into focus.